# pass json string thru jquery variable

Tags: jquery, json

im working in NFC reader that accept a json string

when i post the json string thru input text it is accepted:

```
socket.emit('pushTagInfo', $('#m').val());
```

but when i try to assign it to variable and send it like this:

```
var jsonform = '{ "patientId": "1111111111111111112\n", "timestamp": "Fri Sep 11 01:18:54 2015\n", "name": "Patient Name\n", "tel": "01*-*******\n", "center": "Center 1\n", "blood": "Blood Group\n", "infection": "none\n" }';
socket.emit('pushTagInfo', jsonform);
```

the error is: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token]

what do u think is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape `\` to `\\`(double slash), otherwise the string won't be a valid json string (`\n` is new line which break it).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use an object rather than a string?

```
var jsonform = {
    patientId: "1111111111111111112\n",
    timestamp: "Fri Sep 11 01:18:54 2015\n",
    name: "Patient Name\n",
    tel: "01*-*******\n",
    center: "Center 1\n",
    blood: "Blood Group\n",
    infection: "none\n"
}
socket.emit('pushTagInfo', jsonform);
```

Comment: no, it accepts only this format    { "patientId": "1111111111111111112\n", "timestamp": "Fri Sep 11 01:18:54 2015\n", "name": "Patient Name\n", "tel": "01*-*******\n", "center": "Center 1\n", "blood": "Blood Group\n", "infection": "none\n" }